# Deploy a triggered webjob

Tags: devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-webjobs-triggered

I use Azure DevOps Release pipeline that creates (automatically) and deploys a webjob using the "Azure App Service deploy" task. The webjob type is created as "continous".
I need the job to be created as "triggered".

Comment: Hi @Xile, may i know if there's any update? The point is you need to prepare the folder structure so the web job type can be recognized. Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the webjob type in `WebJobs Folder Structure`. Use .net webjob as example, you can `DotNetCoreCLI@2` to publish the webjobs with structure `App_Data/jobs/triggered` for `triggered` type, or `App_Data/jobs/continuous` for `continuous` type. Then create the zip file for release.

[image]

In `Azure App Service deploy` task, specify the zip file.
[image]

After deployment, check the webjob on azure,  the job type is `triggered`.

[image]

You can follow the [link](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-webjobs-dotnet-core-build-depoy/) for the detail steps. You can also find this info in official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#webjob-types):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change your Azure DevOps Release pipeline in order to create and deploy a "triggered" WebJob instead of a "continuous" one, you need to adjust the configuration in your pipeline.

Edit the "Azure App Service deploy" task within your pipeline and specify the WebJob type as "triggered". This can be done by adding an App Setting or modifying the deployment script.

Ensure the `settings.job` file in your deployment package (if using a `.zip` file) indicates `"type": "triggered"`. Also, check your build process to make sure the WebJob package is correctly configured for a triggered job.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers from above are similar. Thanks a lot!
I was able to solve the problem by setting the job's path to "triggered" in Azure "App Service --> Configuration --> Path mappings"
[image] I did not add a settings.job or update the pipeline with an "app settings".